# How to create a xml (encoding utf-16BE) and send as stream in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, httpwebrequest, utf

I'm sending a Xml as stream using HttpWebRequest but i receive the following response: "Content is not allowed in prolog"

I should use the encoding UTF-16BE, but i don't know how.

My current code:

```
 private void sendXml(string protocolo, string path)
    {
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("user:password"));
        string authorization = String.Concat("Basic ", base64);

        String finalResult;
        HttpWebRequest hwrRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://address/"+protocolo);

        hwrRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        hwrRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
        hwrRequest.Method = "PUT";

        string finalXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16BE""?>....";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(finalXML);

        hwrRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream putStream = hwrRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            putStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)hwrRequest.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            finalResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
            visualiza.Text = visualiza.Text + "\n " + finalResult;
        }
    }
```

Method to generate xmlDocument

```
private void geraXML()
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        byte[] xml = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16BE""?>...");

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xml, true);
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        string caminho = path/+"xmldoc.xml";            
        string nomeArquivo = "xmldoc.xml";
        xmlDoc.Save(caminho);                      

        geraHASH(caminho, nomeArquivo);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Encoding` class has - ​[Big​Endian​Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode?view=netframework-4.7#System_Text_Encoding_BigEndianUnicode)

> Gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format that uses the big endian byte order.

So, you can change your code to use this (instead of ASCII

```
        string finalXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16BE""?>";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(finalXML);
```

If you are really interested in the fascinating world of Unicode and encoding, you can look at [this](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

Comment: I did what you sad, but i'm facing other problem. before send the finalXML, i have a method that create a XmlDocument from the string finalXML and generate a hash used to request a protocol. And than i use this protocol number to send the finalXML. When the Webservice receive the stream, they generate a new hash to compare with the hash code used to request a protocol. and that is the problem. the hash code is different.

Comment: in this post i explain more the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333005/why-when-i-insert-encoding-utf-16be-in-xml-tha-hash-is-different